# Why is a username coming back empty from LookupAccountSid and suser_sname when resolving the SID for a newly created user in Active Directory?

Tags: .net, security, t-sql, winapi, active-directory

We have a computed column in our SQL Server 2008 R2 database that is specified as `(suser_sname([USERSID]))`. When a new user is created in our program, it creates an Active Directory user and then inserts a record into the database with the new user's SID into the column `[USERSID]`.

If someone attempts to open the new user's record from the database immediately after creating it, the computed username is always blank. It can take several seconds for the username to resolve. This only happens when the user is created in Active Directory and does not happen when creating users on the local machine.

I have tried performing the logic in code, as opposed to the database, by using [`LookupAccountSid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but receive an `ERROR_NONE_MAPPED` after making this call.

I have also tried using [`SecurityIdentifier.Translate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.translate.aspx) with similar results to `LookupAccountSid`, which throws `IdentityNotMappedException`.

If I pause execution for several seconds during debugging before either of these calls are made, the correct value is returned.

Why is the username value unable to be returned for several seconds after creating a new Active Directory user? Is there any way to force this value to be returned correctly any faster - or wait for it to be available (aside from sleeping and rechecking the value)?

Comment: What's your AD setup? Do you have multiple DC's in your AD network?

Comment: We've got 2 DC's installed on 2008 Active Directory.

Comment: The domain is a Windows 2003 domain, one DC machine is Windows Server 2003 and the other is Windows Server 2008 R2.